# Prove that the sequence $(\frac{n^2}{n!})$ converge using epsilon delta definition.

Tags: limits

> Prove that the sequence $(\frac{n^2}{n!})$ converge using epsilon delta definition.

I have never seen limit involving factorial, do anyone has any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: if $n>3$, then $n!=n(n-1)(n-2)((n-3)!)>(n-2)^3$. So, for $n>3$: $\frac{n^2}{n!}<\frac{n^2}{(n-2)^3}=(\frac{n}{n-2})^2\cdot \frac{1}{n-2}$.

Comment: Can we use $n!\geq n$?

Comment: how @ᴊᴀsᴏɴ ????

Comment: Ah, I know what's wrong. But how should I choose $N$?